# Box API Create folder

Tags: box-api

I'm a developer and new to box.

I'm trying to create folders using Box API 2.0. I have created an application and got the api key. I have successfully obtained the authorization token for my login "pari@exeterpremedia.com".

Using these credentials when I try to create a folder using the following:
url: "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/folders/321654595?response_type=xml"
xml: "`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><request><api_key>API_KEY</api_key><auth_token>AUTH_TOKEN</auth_token><name>New Folder</name></request>`"

I get the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error><status>401</status><code>unauthorized</code><help-url>http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors</help-url><message>Unauthorized</message><request-id>1341258286500ca4843dfa7</request-id></error>
```

I use perl and "LWP::UserAgent & HTTP::Request::Common" modules for http calls.

Am I going down the correct path or missing something that is obvious.

Thanks,
Pari
pari@exeterpremedia.com

Answer (score 1):

A well-formatted request to create a folder should look like:

```
POST https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/{parent folder id}.xml
```

with a body of

```
<folder>
<name>
{the folder name}
</name>
</folder>
```

Note the following things:

1. The base URL is **https://api.box.com/2.0**, not www.box.com and not over http
2. `.xml` is appended to the end of the request to signify that xml is being sent and expected to be returned
3. There is an enclosing `<folder>` tag around the data which is different from the way the JSON is sent.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. Tried per your suggestion.
But I still get the same 'unathorized' error. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly familiar with using XML with Box's API, but I'm not sure that you can provide the authentication information in the body of the request.  You should try putting the authentication information into a header like shown in their docs [here](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-create-a-new-folder).

Basically try putting the auth information in an Authorization HTTP header of the following format:

```
Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN
```